# How to install linux tools

Tags: linux, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to install some library, it asked me to install the following first:

linux-tools-virtual 3.13.0.35.42
  linux-tools-lowlatency 3.13.0.35.42
  linux-tools-generic-lts-trusty 3.13.0.35.42
  linux-tools-generic-lts-saucy 3.13.0.35.42
  linux-tools-generic 3.13.0.35.42
You should explicitly select one to install.

E: Package 'linux-tools' has no installation candidate

I am using aws instance as ubuntu user, version 14.

Comment: To the off-topic voters:  `linux-tools` is something that one can use for development, so I don't see how it's off-topic here.

Answer (score 4):

A quick look at `apt-cache search linux-tools` reveals that even apt-get doesn't know which one you're talking about.  There's a *lot* of those packages that are similarly named.

Be **explicit** about which one it is you need to install.  Since I don't know which one you require for your application, I can't recommend a specific, exact one for you to install that I know will work 100%.  But the `linux-tools-generic` and `linux-tools-virtual` seem to be promising.  Look into those packages and see if they contain the libraries you need.

Comment: Also, he can use synaptic and have a nice GUI with which to browse the various options

Comment: No, not on a server he can't.  He's using an AWS instance.

Comment: I know which lib and how to install it:   sudo apt-get install linux-tools-generic-lts-trusty  But,afterward, when install other libraries, it said the same thing again.